# Auto-generated error messages for Express-Validator

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, express-validator

I want to create an Express API and validate my request input with `express-validator`. Currently this is my validation middleware

```
protected validate = async (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
    const validationErrors: Result<ValidationError> = validationResult(request);

    if (!validationErrors.isEmpty()) {
        response.status(422).json({ errors: validationErrors.array() });
    } else {
        next();
    }
};
```

and my basic validation setup looks like

```
public persist = [
    body('username')
        .isString()
        .withMessage('username must be of type string.')
        .isLength({ min: 1 })
        .withMessage('username must be at least one character long.')
        .exists()
        .withMessage('username is required.'),
    body('password')
        .isString()
        .withMessage('password must be of type string.')
        .isLength({ min: 1 })
        .withMessage('password must be at least one character long.')
        .exists()
        .withMessage('password is required.'),
    this.validate,
];
```

When I call `POST /users` to create a new user I get a detailed error response on invalid inputs. When I remove all the custom error messages I get this response

```
[
    {
        "msg": "Invalid value",
        "param": "username",
        "location": "body"
    },
    {
        "msg": "Invalid value",
        "param": "password",
        "location": "body"
    }
]
```

Is there a way to get auto-generated error messages or do I really have to write these error messages on my own?

Comment: You can create an express middleware which take the constraints as argument as an json object for example and which can do the validation for you, while formatting properly the custom message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the validator is trying to tell you where it thinks it has found an error and since it does not have the custom error string(s), it falls back on the (rather ugly) "element/location" scheme.

#### Approach 1

The most reasonable way would be to have a custom error message for each field.
Seeing that the error messages are rather repetitive, it would make sense to move them out of the validator definition, and maybe create a very simple "getter" function that would do some basic templating. Then, your code becomes a fair bit nicer:

```
const MSG_TYPE_STR = '{{field}} must be of type string.'

function getMessage(fieldName: string, msgID: string): string {
   // Templating magic happens here, Regex or whatever other method you prefer
}
...

body('username')
        .isString()
        .withMessage(getMessage('username', MSG_TYPE_STR)

....
```

This way, you will still get nicely formatted error messages and you would not have copy-paste the same string over and over again

#### Approach 2

You could *conceivably* add post-processing to the validation error (i.e. take the ugly output and do some calculations and transform it to a nicer output). This would be a considerably harder approach, as you would have to break down the rules to atomic checks and your validation scheme becomes very long, and still it's a fair bit of work

#### Approach 3

This is not so much an "approach" as a suggestion - you may switch to a different validator, like Joi for example, which has a much more reasonable default logic around error messages

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I think I will switch to joi :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Alex's suggestions, especially about the [Joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi) part.

Just wanted to mention one more opportunity. To pass to the client error key codes. 
Example:

> usernameTooShort

This can be handled in the client and will be useful if at some point you decide to add localization to your app. You'll have a key-value object on the front-end that handles the messages depending on the language, that your user has picked.

Good luck!